# Como usar uma variavel js , em outra pagina html

Tags: javascript

Fiz um pequeno programa, que voce escolhe uma imagem e essa mesma imagem aparece em outra pagina

```js
var hulk = $('#hulk1').click(function () {
    var hulkk = document.getElementById("hulk1").src;
    if (window.location.href = "modo.html"


})
var ironman = $('#ironman1').click(function () {
    window.location.href = "modo.html"
    var iron = document.getElementById("ironman1");

})
var captain = $('#captain1').click(function () {
    window.location.href = "modo.html"
    var iron = document.getElementById("captain1");

})
var woman = $('#woman1').click(function () {
    window.location.href = "modo.html"
    var iron = document.getElementById("woman1");

})
var spider = $('#spiderman1').click(function () {
    window.location.href = "modo.html"
    var iron = document.getElementById("spiderman1");

})
var thor = $('#thor1').click(function () {
    window.location.href = "modo.html"
    var iron = document.getElementById("thor1");

})
```

Comment: Poderia ser mais claro e explicar com detalhes o que quer fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Apesar de sua pergunta não estar com a formatação correta, deu pra entender. Enfim, simplesmente linke o arquivo js na sua página HTML vou dar um exemplo bem básico:

**arquivo.js**:

```
function dizeroi(){
var msg = "Ola"
alert(msg)
}
```

**index.html**:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="pt-br">
 <head>
 <title>Título da página</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="arquivo.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body onload="dizeroi()">
 <h1>Um título qualquer</h1>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**Do jeito que quer fazer, no js**:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 16; i++){    
var img = document.createElement("
img"); //criar elemento img
var img.src = "imagens/letters1/" + i + ".jpg"; 
//atribuindo a propriedade source da imagem    
document.getElementById("
demo").appendChild(img); //adicionando imagem como filha de demo
}
```

**Do jeito que quer fazer, no HTML**:

```
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Se quiser fazer com imagens mesmo esquema só muda o códico ...

Comment: Man vlw mesmo , fiquei perdido na hora da pergunta mais vlw mesmo

Comment: Se resolveu o seu problema marque a resposta como resolvida "✅" ajuda no padrão de qualidade do site e as pessoas que tiverem a mesma dúvida que a sua.

Comment: man tipo assim , na hora que eu clicar na imagem, ele salva esse evento de click em uma variavel, e na outra pagina eu posso chamar essa variavel no caso a imagem

Comment: Editei e acrecentei a resposta do jeito que quer fazer.